# tikz box positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hi i am new to latex and I want to place a gray box to the left side of the document to use the box as a sidebar.

Here is what I have tried:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{sidecolor}{HTML}{E7E7E7}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [rectangle, fill=sidecolor, anchor=north, minimum width=9cm, minimum height=\paperheight+1cm] (box) at (-5cm,0.5cm){};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But the output is shifted for some reason
[image: the screenshot of the output document]

So the question is that, How does one create a box that covers the entire left 5cm of the page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With use of the `tikzpagenodes` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{sidecolor}{HTML}{E7E7E7}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [fill=sidecolor, minimum width=9cm, minimum height=\textheight,
       above right] (box) at (current page text area.south west)    {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

**Edit:**
Unfortunately your question is not entirely clear. Do you like that gray box is

- at left border of text are as is produced with above MWE (Minimal Working Example), or
- at left border of page as produce the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{sidecolor}{HTML}{E7E7E7}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [fill=sidecolor, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=\paperheight,
       above right] at (current page.south west)    {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:**
For final (showed) form of compilation result both MWE had to be compiled  -- due to `tikzpicture` options `remember picture,overlay` -- at least twice.

Answer (score 2):

One option you might want to consider is changing the document class. If you use \documentclass{standalone}[tikz] instead of \documentclass{article}, then the dimensions of the page that Latex compiles is limited to the features you have added to it. So as long as nothing is left-adjacent to your side-page box, then the left-side of the page will be occupied by this box and the gray side box will never be shifted out of view.

Tweaking your code a bit:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}[tikz]
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{sidecolor}{HTML}{E7E7E7}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{box}=[rectangle, fill=sidecolor, anchor=north, minimum width=5cm, minimum height=\paperheight+1cm]]
\node at (-5cm,5cm) [box]{};
\filldraw (0,1) circle (1); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I just added the black circle to widen the view a little (otherwise the whole output would have been the side gray box).